# После нажатия кнопки, кнопка становится цветной

Tags: html, css

Необходимо изменение цвета кнопки, после её нажатия, но проблема в том, что при её нажатии браузер обновляет страницу. Кнопка в виде чек-бокса, нажал-отметил.

```css
.login-btn1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #33b5e5;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  right: 3px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<button class="login-btn1" name="stack ">VK</button>
```

Comment: У кнопок по-умолчанию тип `submit`, вот оно и обновляет страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**type="button"**

```
<button type="button" class="login-btn1" name="stack ">VK</button>
```

> как получить цвет при нажатии на кнопку

```js
function testFunction(element) {
  // without jQuery:
  var backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor;
  console.log(backgroundColor);
  // with jQuery:
  console.log($(element).css("background-color"));
}
```

```css
.login-btn1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  right: 3px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="login-btn1" name="stack " 
  onclick="testFunction(this)">VK</button>
```

Comment: Можно узнать, как получить цвет при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 0):

```
  .login-btn2:focus {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.login-btn2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #33b5e5;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
```